# POST method for RESTful API

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest, post

I'm still a beginner for .NET, C#, RESTful API. Now, I'm learning the POST method in RESTful API. Here is the sample coding of POST method, but I still can't get the meaning of the coding. Can anyone provide me an explanation for each line of the coding in a clearly understand way? Or if you don't mind, can you explain it to me by using comment style? For example:

```
public string message; //to declare message for what use...`

public class MessageController : ApiController
{
    // GET api/values
    public class MessageToShow
    {
        public string message;
        public string from;
    }

    public List<MessageToShow> Get()
    {   

         var x = new cheeAdDCClf3rfFREntities();

         var  y=x.messages.Take(100);
         List<MessageToShow> messageToShow = new List<MessageToShow>();
         foreach (var xx in y)
         {
             MessageToShow m = new MessageToShow();
             member me = x.members.FirstOrDefault(j => j.ID == xx.from);
             if (me != null)
             {
                 m.from = me.username;
                 m.message = xx.message1;
                 messageToShow.Add(m);
             }

         }
         return messageToShow;

    }

    // POST api/values
    public void Post(int memberid, dynamic value)
    {
        var x = new cheeAdDCClf3rfFREntities();
        message m = new message();
        m.ID = x.messages.Max(record => record.ID) + 1;
        m.from = memberid;
        m.message1 = value.value;
        x.messages.Add(m);
        x.SaveChanges();

    }     
}
}
```

I would be very appreciate if anyone would like to share me your knowledge on programming. Thank you so much!!! ^_^

Comment: Unfortunately, SO isn't the forum for tutorials. You will be better off going to a site like [ASP.Net - Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api) where you will find information and more resources where you can really learn instead of just the (specific) pieces.

Comment: I'm sorry if I made any mistake. @@ Actually, I was told by my senior that I could try to share and ask the questions about programming at this site. Anyway, thank you Mr. EdSF for your information and suggestion. I will try to learn it from the scratch. =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you posted code for both a `GET` and `POST` method.

When I make a `GET` to your API:

```
public List<MessageToShow> Get()
{   

     // Looks like EntityFramework? Represents the items already in database
     var x = new cheeAdDCClf3rfFREntities();

     // Take to top 100 item already in the database
     var  y=x.messages.Take(100);

     // Create a new list to hold the messages we will return
     List<MessageToShow> messageToShow = new List<MessageToShow>();

     // For each message in the 100 we just took
     foreach (var xx in y)
     {
         MessageToShow m = new MessageToShow();

         // Get the details of the member that send this message
         member me = x.members.FirstOrDefault(j => j.ID == xx.from);

         // If we found the member, create a message to show
         //  (populating the message and the username of the member
         //  who sent it)
         if (me != null)
         {
             m.from = me.username;
             m.message = xx.message1;
             messageToShow.Add(m);
         }

     }

     // Return the list of messages we just created to the caller of the API
     return messageToShow;
}
```

When I `POST` to your API this is what happens:

```
public void Post(int memberid, dynamic value)
{
    // Gets the items already in the database
    var x = new cheeAdDCClf3rfFREntities();

    // Create a new message object
    message m = new message();

    // Find the highest ID already in the database, then add 1. This is the
    //  ID for our new item
    m.ID = x.messages.Max(record => record.ID) + 1;

    // The 'from' property is set to the memberId that the user passed in the POST
    m.from = memberid;

    // The 'message' property is set to whatever dynamic value is passed in the POST
    m.message1 = value.value;

    // Add the message to the database
    x.messages.Add(m);
    x.SaveChanges();
}
```

To understand more about REST, you can read this:

[A beginners Guide To HTTP and REST](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/a-beginners-guide-to-http-and-rest--net-16340)

The code you posted actually looks more like EntityFramework, which is a way of interacting with a database. It's not specific to APIs.

You can find our more about EF here:

[EntityFramework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/data/ee712907)

Comment: Thank you Mr Dave S for willing to share your knowledge with me!! I'm really appreciate it. I'm actually trying to integrate my mobile application with database using the Framework, ASP.NET. From what I know, API is an interface for different platform to connect together. So, I'm currently learning on how it works. Thanks for sharing the knowledge and the information above. I will try my best. ^^ Have a nice day~